# "No code at ..." error in Goland IDE

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide, goland

I added two checkpoints for debugging code in `Goland IDE`. I don't know why but debugger can't see the first checkpoint and just skip it and moved to the second one.

[image]

When I navigate the mouse cursor over the first checkpoint, it shows me an error 
`"No such code at ... "`:

[image]

Could you explain why such behavior happens?

Comment: Please open an issue on the tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go because in order to solve this it requires some information from your logs which needs to be uploaded. Thank you.